# All sources of BFA items by item level in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I wonder about all sources of items in BFA content, and IL which can be dropped (non forged), I know I can get items from dungeons, and PvP but want to know all sources of items by item level, I am not sure mainly about item level of items which can be dropped from elites in warfronts, or I not sure how item level rewards from mythics+ scale? So please can you name me here all sources and item levels which can be obtained in the last patch (only rare and epic gear)?

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad for our site. However, if you need a list of ALL items that can be gotten in WoW, check out https://www.wowhead.com/, they're pretty much the default for questions like that.

Comment: Title says BFA, so it's not all of wow.

Comment: All of an expansion is still an enormous amount of content, and any answer here is likely to just be copied from a wiki or database.

Comment: @Pyritie it doesn't matter where you get the answer from. In fact, a lot of the answers on this site can be found in some wiki or guide. And since the expansion is pretty new the list is still short enough. Only because it will be pretty broad in a year doesn't mean it is too broad now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of basic (non-titanforged) gear item levels obtained at max lvl in BfA.

- Rare Mobs: 273
- World Quests: 275-340 (scales with your item level)
- Crafted Items: 300, 355, 370, 385 (tier 1-4)
- Normal Dungeon: 310
- Purchasable Cloaks (honored rep at BfA factions): 320
- Expeditions: 325
- Heroic Dungeons: 325
- Purchasable Items (revered at BfA factions): 335
- Mythic Dungeons: 340
- Uldir Raid: 340, 355, 370, 385 (LFR, Normal, Heroic, Mythic)
- Engineering Goggles: 340
- Arathi (Warfront) rare mobs: 340
- World Quests (Emissary rewards): 340
- Reward for winning a Warfront: 340
- PvP rated games: 340, 350, 360, 365, 370, 375 (depeding on your rating)
- Weekly M+ Chest: 340-385

  - 2,3: 355 (or 340 Azerite Armor)
  - 4,5: 360 (or 355 AA)
  - 6: 365 (or 355 AA)
  - 7,8: 370 (or 370 AA)
  - 9: 370, incl AA
  - 10: 380 (or 385 AA)
- Mythic+ Dungeons: 345-370:

  - 2,3: 345
  - 4: 350
  - 5,6: 355
  - 7: 360
  - 8,9: 365
  - 10+: 370
- Purchasable items (exalted): 350
- Azerite Items from Champions of Azeroth (exalted): 355
- Darkmoon Trinkets (Inscription crafting): 355
- World Boss on Kul'Tiras/Zandalar: 355
- PvP Weekly Chest: 355-385 (depending on your rating)
- Warfront World Boss: 370
- Warfront Weekly Quest: 370

Comment: Edits are not meant to add information that was not included by the author.

Comment: Timewalking gear is supposed to be 320, but seems to be buggy right now.